How can I retrieve GIDs for category metafield values when syncing products to Shopify via GraphQL API?
I’m working on a product sync system to upload products from my backend system to Shopify via the Shopify GraphQL API. I can create products with standard metafields, but I’d also like to use category metafields to organize them more effectively.
Here’s where I’m stuck:
I’ve mapped Shopify’s taxonomy category IDs to my system, so I can easily assign products to categories.
However, Shopify requires that I pass the GID (Global ID) for each value within a category metafield (e.g., specific colors or sizes for products).
While it’s possible to manually retrieve the GID for each value from Shopify’s UI and then use it in the API, this isn’t scalable—I’m dealing with around 4000 products across multiple categories. Ideally, I need a way to programmatically fetch the GIDs for the available values in category metafields.
Here’s an example GraphQL request I’m using to create a product:
  productCreate(input: $input, media: $media) {
    product {
      id
      title
      metafields(first: 10) {
        edges {
          node {
            
            namespace
            key
            value
          }
        }
      }
      media(first: 10) {
        nodes {
          alt
          mediaContentType
          preview {
            status
          }
        }
      }
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}

Here is an example Input
{
  "input": {
    "metafields": [
      {
         "namespace": "shopify",
         "key": "color-pattern",
          "value": "[\"gid://shopify/Metaobject/105144877321\"]"
      },
      {
         "namespace": "shopify",
         "key": "bulb-size",
          "value": "[\"gid://shopify/TaxonomyValue/8468\"]"
      
      }
    ],
    "title": "Helmet Nova 6",
    "category": "gid://shopify/TaxonomyCategory/hg-13-5-5"
  },
  "media": [
    {
      "originalSource": "https://cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/brochure/assets/sell/image/image-@artdirection-large-1ba8d5de56c361cec6bc487b747c8774b9ec8203f392a99f53c028df8d0fb3fc.png",
      "alt": "Gray helmet for bikers",
      "mediaContentType": "IMAGE"
    },
    {
      "originalSource": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4L8VbGRibj8&list=PLlMkWQ65HlcEoPyG9QayqEaAu0ftj0MMz",
      "alt": "Testing helmet resistance against impacts",
      "mediaContentType": "EXTERNAL_VIDEO"
    }
  ]
}

In this example:
The color-pattern field works because I manually created and mapped a metaobject in the Shopify UI and then retrieved the GID.
However, replicating this process for all products and categories would be extremely time-consuming.
Question:
Is there a way to retrieve the GIDs for available values in category metafields programmatically, or is there a recommended approach for handling this kind of batch metafield mapping?
Any help or guidance would be appreciated! Thank you.

Try this mutation for fetch the categories data:
{
  taxonomyNode(id: "gid://shopify/TaxonomyNode/TAXONOMY_ID") {
    ... on TaxonomyLeaf {
      id
      name
      metafieldDefinitions(first: 10) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            name
            values {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  name
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

